# Removing duplication in AngularJS Factory

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have multiple API calls so I created a service however I would like to find a way to remove the duplication

```
myAppServices.factory('apiService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getDocuments: function () {
            return $http.get('/api/autodeskdocuments/1')
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (typeof response.data == 'object') {
                        return response.data;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
            });
        },

        getSharePoint: function () {
            return $http.get('/api/sharepointheaderdata/1')
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (typeof response.data == 'object') {
                        return response.data;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
        }
    };
});
```

As you can see both functions has some duplication with the .then(...) Any suggestions as to make this cleaner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the whole ajax to a function.

```
myAppServices.factory('apiService', function ($http, $q) {
    var get = function(endpoint) {
        return $http.get(endpoint)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (typeof response.data == 'object') {
                        return response.data;
                    } else {
                        // invalid response
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }
                }, function (response) {
                    // something went wrong
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
            });
    }
    return {
        getDocuments: function () {
            return get('/api/autodeskdocuments/1');
        },

        getSharePoint: function () {
            return get('/api/sharepointheaderdata/1');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: wow, thanks... that makes more sense and so much cleaner!